# Encode/Obscure/Hash IP Addresses

Tags: php, hash

I generate a `MD5 Hash` for every `IP` in the database. The `Hash` will be visible on the Website, the `IP` not.

I generate the `Hash` like this at the moment:

```
$ip   = '1.2.3.4';
$salt = '1024 random characters';
$hash = md5(sha1($salt).md5($ip).sha1($salt));
```

I thought it might be harder or impossible to decode the `Hash` back to an `IP` this way if you don't have the salt. Am i doing it right, am i partially or totally wrong?

The `Hash` is used to fetch an image which has the `Hash` in the filename. And because this image is visible on the website, **i don't want others to know to which ip the image (hash) belongs to**. I don't need to reverse it to the original IP. I need a MD5 Hash in the end because the API i'm talking to expects MD5.

**UPDATE:** VolkerK mentioned php's `hash_hmac` function. i read the manual and now i'm using this inside `md5()`, like this: `$hash = md5(hash_hmac('sha1', $ip, $salt));` I guess this is the better approach?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why are you hashing the IP address?

Comment: Exactly why are you hashing ip adresses?

Comment: salting doesn't really make it difficulter to decode the ip. You can display the salt to anyone, and the security level stays the same (although you shouldn't do it). Salting is useful for storing passwords, because a hacker can't decode standard passwords so easily, if he already got access to your database. However, it's useless for storing IP's, as the propability that several users have the same IP is very low.

Comment: why i'm hashing the ip: because the hash is used to fetch an image which has the hash in the filename. and because this image is visible on the website, i don't want others know which ip's (user) this image is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question what you're actually trying to achieve still standing my generic answer is not to roll your own hash/authentication/... scheme but to use a proven mechanism (i.e. it has been analyzed, its bounds/limits are documented and best practices guides are available).
In this case the most likely canditate is [Hash-based message authentication code (HMAC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) which is available e.g. through php's [hash extension](http://docs.php.net/function.hash-hmac) .

Comment: i updated the questions to make more clear what i'm trying to do.